# JQueryui - Manage connected sortable lists forcing only one element by list

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Jqueryui connected sortable lists and I would like to drop elements only when the connected list is empty, so I have to force the user to add maximum 1 element.
Using Jquery droppable is not allowed.

So, How can I manage JQueryui connected list to restrict the number of elements inside?
I want sortable1 and sortable2 to accept only one element from sortable0.

```
<ul id="sortable0" class="connectedSortable"> 
  <li> word1 </li> <li> word2 </li> <li> wordN </li>
 </ul>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> </ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable"> </ul>

$(function() {
  $( "#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({ connectWith: ".connectedSortable" });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a solution like this

```
$("#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: "#sortable0, .connectedSortable:not(:has(li))"
});
```

This enables you to move exactly one element from `#sortable0` to `#sortable1` or/and `#sortable2`. You can also move them back to `#sortable0`. or move it from e.g. `#sortable1` to `#sortable2` if `#sortable2` is still empty

Check this [test case](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nSjbP/1/show)

---

The selector I wrote in `connectWith` is evaluated everytime you drag an element around. thus if `sortable1/2` already contain an element they aren't marked as `connectWith` and aren't available as target.

<strike>If you need a more fine tuned control e.g. `sortable0` accepting any number of elements, `sortable1` exactly 0 or 1 and `sortable2` 0 or 1 or 2 elements you can use</strike>

```
$("#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: "#sortable0, #sortable1:not(:has(li)), #sortable2:not(:has(li:eq(1)))"
});
```

Edit: the striked out code doesn't work need to look into it

Comment: This was exactly what I need, thank you very much. But I'm still wondering about how to define the number of elements for each list.

Answer (score 0):

As there's no default option for this, you must use an event like `beforeStop` or `receive`.

```
$( "#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable(
   { connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
     beforeStop: function(event,ui){
       // Do the check
     }
   }
);
```

for example.

Comment: I was trying this before but I couldn find the check... Could be something like this  if($(ui.helper).length > 1) return; but is not working...